# Flutter Animation for emojies

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

please watch the small video for a clear understanding

https://youtu.be/y_7xxIWHraw

i have flutter app that has emoji as image and on background that is the circular container I want to animate emoji to popup a little bit and back to normal when tapping again

I have the code below that is simple design no idea about the animation so I am looking for help

```
 Container(
            height: 90,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/love.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                           /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                      //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Love',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/happy.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                        //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Happy',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/sad.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                        //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Sad',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/depressed.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                        //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Depressed',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/worried.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                        //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Worried',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/confused.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                        //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Confused',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                                width: 40.0,
                                height: 40.0,
                                child: Image.asset('assets/irritated.png'))),
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          /* image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/emoji1.png',),
                            )*/
                        ),
                        //  child:
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Irritated',style: TextStyle(color: textcolor,fontSize: 14,fontFamily: medium),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
  GestureDetector(
      onTap:(){
        setState((){
          isTap=!isTap;
        });
      },
      child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 60.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        child: Center(
                            child: AnimatedContainer(
                              duration:Duration(milliseconds:100),
                                width:isTap? 40.0:20,
                                height:isTap? 40.0:20,
                                child: Image.network('assets/irritated.png'))),                              
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                         ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 2,),
                      Text('Love',),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
```

We can improve a little more. We can create the EmojiItem widget, manage animations by creating the selected Index variable in the main widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int? selectedIndex;
  List<String> imagePathList = ['assets/happy.png', 'assets/happy.png'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 2,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = selectedIndex != index ? index : null;
                });
              },
              child: EmojiItem(
                isSelected: index == selectedIndex,
                imagePath: imagePathList[index],
              ));
        });
  }
}

class EmojiItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final String imagePath;
  EmojiItem({Key? key, required this.isSelected, required this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 60.0,
            height: 60.0,
            child: Center(
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    width: isSelected ? 40.0 : 20,
                    height: isSelected ? 40.0 : 20,
                    child: Image.asset(imagePath))),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFF9EAD3),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 2,
          ),
          Text(
            'Love',
            style: TextStyle(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```